# Add default open logic for a react Collapse component

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I created this react Collapse component with `react-spring` which have the open and close functionality.

I want to have a **defaultOpen** prop, so the content stays open on initial render then it use **isOpen** state for closing and opening.

How can i do that?

here is a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fire-wsvml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For that, you will need to have `Collapsible` component own state**

And pass `defaultOpen` from the parent component

Something like this:

```
const Collapse = ({ defaultOpen = false, children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(defaultOpen)
  const [ref, { height: viewHeight }] = useMeasure()
  const { height, opacity } = useSpring({
    from: { height: 0, opacity: 1 },
    to: {
      height: isOpen ? viewHeight : 0,
      opacity: isOpen ? 1 : 0,
    },
  })

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(isOpen => !isOpen)}>{isOpen ? 'close' : 'open'}</button>
      <Content style={{ opacity, height }}>
        <a.div ref={ref}>{children}</a.div>
      </Content>
    </>
  )
}
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit eloquent-mccarthy-ce2w7]

Comment: thank you. yeah that's one way so solve it, but i want to have both functionality.imagine there is more collapse components and i want some of them to be open initially with defaultOpen prop and the rest use is open state.

Comment: For that, you would need a state for individual Collapsible component, then pass the defaultValue from outside. I updated the answer

Comment: For every component which has a `defaultValue`, `defaultValue` only works when you don't provide an actual value to it. Including native HTML select, radio or checkbox element.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to make use of the property `defaultOpen` provide it to the App component like this:

```
export default function App({ defaultOpen = true }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(defaultOpen)

  return (
    <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
      ...
    </Collapse>
  )
}
```